# Core.LargeFileUpload File Not Found Cant find Folder

Tags: c#, sharepoint, large-file-upload

I am trying to upload files larger than 2MB to SharePoint365 using `Core.LargeFileUpload`.

I have altered it to suit my code but it fails to find my Folder. I get an error response '`File Not Found`' and a 0 byte file is written to the list

I have tried using :

```
Folder folder = docs.RootFolder.Folders.GetByUrl(vFolder);
```

to no avail, best I get is a 0 byte file in the folder I want but the error is still "File Not Found"

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UploadSH365
{

    public class FileUploadService
    {
        public string Upload(string vURL, out string vURLout, string vUName, string vPWD, string vList, string vFolder, string vFileName, byte[] vAttachment, Dictionary<string, string> metadata, bool overwrite)
        {       
            string strMsg = "";
            vURLout = "";
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vURL))

                return "Empty URL field";
            int blockSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            try
            {
                long fileSize = vAttachment.Length;
              //  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile;
                Guid uploadId = Guid.NewGuid();

                // Ensure that target library exists, create if is missing

                using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(vURL))
                     {                     
                    SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
                         foreach (char c in vPWD.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
                         clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(vUName, passWord);
                         Web web = clientContext.Web;


                    List docs = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(vList);
                    clientContext.Load(docs, l => l.RootFolder);
                    // Get the information about the folder that will hold the file
                    clientContext.Load(docs.RootFolder, f => f.ServerRelativeUrl);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    // File object 
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile;

                    // Calculate block size in bytes
                    // int blockSize = fileChunkSizeInMB * 1024 * 1024;

                    // Get the information about the folder that will hold the file
                    clientContext.Load(docs.RootFolder, f => f.ServerRelativeUrl);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    ;           
                    // Use large file upload approach
                    ClientResult<long> bytesUploaded = null;

                         Stream fs = null;
                         try
                         {


                        fs = new MemoryStream(vAttachment);
                        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
                        {
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[blockSize];
                            Byte[] lastBuffer = null;
                            long fileoffset = 0;
                            long totalBytesRead = 0;
                            int bytesRead;
                            bool first = true;
                            bool last = false;

                            // Read data from filesystem in blocks 
                            while ((bytesRead = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                            {
                                totalBytesRead = totalBytesRead + bytesRead;

                                // We've reached the end of the file
                                if (totalBytesRead == fileSize)
                                {
                                    last = true;
                                    // Copy to a new buffer that has the correct size
                                    lastBuffer = new byte[bytesRead];
                                    Array.Copy(buffer, 0, lastBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                                }

                                if (first)
                                {
                                    using (MemoryStream contentStream = new MemoryStream())
                                    {
                                        // Add an empty file.
                                        FileCreationInformation fileInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
                                        fileInfo.ContentStream = contentStream;
                                        fileInfo.Url = vFileName;
                                        fileInfo.Overwrite = true;
                                        uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileInfo);

                                        // Start upload by uploading the first slice. 
                                        using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(buffer))
                                        {
                                            // Call the start upload method on the first slice
                                            bytesUploaded = uploadFile.StartUpload(uploadId, s);
                                            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                                            // fileoffset is the pointer where the next slice will be added
                                            fileoffset = bytesUploaded.Value;
                                        }

                                        // we can only start the upload once
                                        first = false;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    // Get a reference to our file
                                    uploadFile = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(docs.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + vFileName);

                                    if (last)
                                    {
                                        // Is this the last slice of data?
                                        using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(lastBuffer))
                                        {
                                            // End sliced upload by calling FinishUpload
                                            uploadFile = uploadFile.FinishUpload(uploadId, fileoffset, s);
                                            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                                            vURLout = vURL + "/" + vList + "/" + vFolder + "/" + vFileName;
                                            // return the file object for the uploaded file
                                            return vURLout;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(buffer))
                                        {
                                            // Continue sliced upload
                                            bytesUploaded = uploadFile.ContinueUpload(uploadId, fileoffset, s);
                                            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                                            // update fileoffset for the next slice
                                            fileoffset = bytesUploaded.Value;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            } // while ((bytesRead = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        }    
                    }
                    finally
                         {
                             if (fs != null)
                             {
                                 fs.Dispose();
                             }
                         }    
                     }                                                 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                strMsg = ex.Message;
            }

            return strMsg;
            // Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

0 Byte File is written to the List instead of the Folder I want.

Comment: What line of code throws the exception?

Answer (score 0):

I used GetFileByURL instead of GetFileByServerRelativeURL

```
  string furl = vURL + "/" + vList + "/" + vFolder + "/" + vFileName;
                                    // Get a reference to our file
                                    uploadFile = clientContext.Web.GetFileByUrl(furl);
```